# Splitting Ajax response wrt div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On my page there are two divs `<div id="Qdiv"></div>` & `<div id="Adiv"></div>`

```
+----------+   +----------+
|  QDIV    |   |  ADIV    |
+----------+   +----------+
```

I am getting response from my ajax which looks like following:

```
<div id="gotoQdiv">Whatever in it should go to Qdiv</div>
<div id="gotoAdiv">Whatever in it should go to Adiv</div>
```

Kindly let me know how can I split this kind of ajax response into two different divs?

```
 $.ajax({url:"demo_test.",success:function(result){
    $("#Qdiv").html(result);
    $("#Adiv").html(result);
  }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `find()` the target elements need to be within a container. In your response, this is not the case, so you need to either `wrap()` them, or change your returned HTML. Here's the first way, using `wrap()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.",
    success:function(result) {
        var $container = $(result).wrap('<div />').parent();
        $("#Qdiv").html($container.find('#gotoQdiv'));
        $("#Adiv").html($container.find('#gotoAdiv'));
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can change your response to include a container:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="gotoQdiv">Whatever in it should go to Qdiv</div>
    <div id="gotoAdiv">Whatever in it should go to Adiv</div>
</div>
```

Then you don't need to `wrap()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.",
    success:function(result) {
        var $container = $(result);
        $("#Qdiv").html($container.find('#gotoQdiv'));
        $("#Adiv").html($container.find('#gotoAdiv'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for giving me a very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to parse the values from that response,

```
  $.ajax({url:"demo_test.",success:function(result){

    $("#Qdiv").html($(result).filter("#gotoQdiv").html());
    $("#Adiv").html($(result).filter("#gotoAdiv").html());
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use .filter to select the div you want:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.",
    success:function(result) {
        $("#Qdiv").html($(result).filter('#gotoQdiv'));
        $("#Adiv").html($(result).filter('#gotoAdiv'));
    }
});
```